# Пересслать сообщение pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
if call.data == 'vyvest':
        if db[str(call.message.chat.id)]["balance"] > 30:
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='❌ Мінімальна сума: 30 Грн', show_alert=True)
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Введіть вашу картку: ')
            admin_id = 'admin id'
            # сообщение юзера должно пересслать админу
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте: `bot.forward_message(id кому переслать, id от какого чата переслать, id сообщения)`